# Toolbar overlaps with tablayout after collapsing Appbarlayout

Tags: android, toolbar, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image: 1][image: after tab pin[![][1][1]]I am working on collapsing toolbar layout,i integrated inside navigation drawer it is working properly in first fragment inside that i scrolled collapsing toolbar to top after that i opened second fragment toolbar is overlapping with tablayout,i don't know what is happening i checked in allways.

code:

```
 private void setToolbarPin(Toolbar toolbar)
    {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams newParams;
        if (params instanceof CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) {
            newParams = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams)params;
        } else {
            newParams = new CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(params);
        }
        newParams.setCollapseMode(CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF);
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(newParams);




      //  toolbar.requestLayout();

    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >
            <View
                android:id="@+id/customView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                ></View>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >


    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can u add some screenshots?

Comment: i am adding toolbar collapsible pin programatically,if i scroll to up collapsible bar and navigate to tablayout one i am getting this overlap